# String.replace performance issue in android 2.2

Tags: java, android

I am writing an android application that loads the HTML page and gets a specific data from it. I've tested it using android 4.0, and everything was fine. Today I've tried to run it on android 2.2 (froyo) and unexpectedly faced with the serious performance leak. My code is following:

```
    ArrayList<News> news = new ArrayList<News>();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(BASE_URL
            + "news_view.php");
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("start", String
            .valueOf(start)));
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, HTTP.UTF_8));
    HttpResponse response = getHttpClientInstance().execute(httpPost);
    HtmlCleaner cleaner = new HtmlCleaner();
    String s = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity(), HTTP.UTF_8);
    TagNode root = cleaner.clean(s);
    TagNode[] list = root.getAllElements(false)[1].getAllElements(false);
    if (list.length == 0)
        throw new ParsingException();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        String header = list[i].getElementsByName("h3", true)[0].getText()
                .toString();
        TagNode footer = list[i].getElementsByName("h3", true)[1];

        String date = footer.getElementsByName("span", true)[0].getText()
                .toString();
        String author = footer.getElementsByName("a", true)[0].getText()
                .toString();
        String target = footer.getElementsByName("a", true)[1]
                .getAttributeByName("href");
(!)     String text = list[i].getText().toString().replace(header, "")
                .replace(footer.getText().toString(), "")
                .replace('\n', ' ').replace("&nbsp;", " ").trim();
        header = header.replace("&nbsp;", " ").trim();
        date = date.replace("&nbsp;", " ").trim();
        text += "\n" + date;
        News n = new News(header, text, target, author, date,
                News.NEWS_PROJECT);
        news.add(n);
    }
```

My application freezes on line that is marked by `(!)` and does not continue. Yes I know that String.replace is the evil, but I didn't expect that my application will stuck so badly because there is no lags on android ICS. Can anyone explain me what is happening?

**EDIT.**
I've replaced the line that is marked by `(!)` with the following code:

```
String text0 = list[i].getText().toString();
String text1 = text0.replace(header, "");
String text2 = text1.replace(footer.getText().toString(), "");
String text3 = text2.replace('\n', ' ');
String text4 = text3.replace("&nbsp;", " ");
String text5 = text4.trim();
```

Nothing changed. My application stucks at the first replace (text1).

Comment: what is the purpose behind replacing?

Comment: Have you tested with the *same* HTML input when comparing performance in ICS and 2.2?

Comment: @Dheeraj V.S., yes data is completely the same.

Comment: Really a single call to `replace` is hanging? That sounds very unlikely. Given that you've got multiple replacements there, have you worked out *which* one is hanging?

Comment: @user1256821 at which iteration of the for loop did you application freeze?

Comment: What do you mean by "leak"?  Does any java.lang.Exception or java.lang.Error occur?

Comment: @Jon Skeet look at the second edit. The first `replace` is hanging.

Comment: @tcb it freezes at the first iteration.

Comment: @user1256821: So at this point, you should be able to extract a *far* shorter example, with hard-coded values for both `text1` and `footer.getText().toString()`. Basically you should be able to provide a *single line* example which hangs. If you can do that, it'll be much easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet Please refer to the last edit.

Comment: Can you show `header` also, please.

Comment: @user1256821: Right, so now experiment until you've got a *short* example string causing the problem. Note that you need two strings - we need the footer text too. Basically you should be able to give a short single line of code which hangs.

Comment: Finally found the error. The `header` was an empty string. Thank everyone who replied to my question. May anyone post an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in the implementation of String.replace() in Android 2.2. I could not find the exact source code for Android 2.2, but I managed to find the source code for Android 2.1. The implementation of the replace method is:

```
public String replace(CharSequence target, CharSequence replacement) {
    if (target == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("target should not be null");
    }
    if (replacement == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException("replacement should not be null");
    }
    String ts = target.toString();
    int index = indexOf(ts, 0);

    if (index == -1)
        return this;

    String rs = replacement.toString();
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(count);
    int tl = target.length();
    int tail = 0;
    do {
        buffer.append(value, offset + tail, index - tail);
        buffer.append(rs);
        tail = index + tl;
    } while ((index = indexOf(ts, tail)) != -1);
    //append trailing chars
    buffer.append(value, offset + tail, count - tail);

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

The do-while loop does not terminate if both `target` and `replacement` are the empty string. Both `index` and `tail` are initialized to zero. `indexOf(ts, tail)` returns the value of `tail`, which is zero. `tail = index + tl` does not increase `tail` because both `index` and `tl` are zero.

This explains the observed behavior. I assume that since user1256821 observed the same behavior in Android 2.2 this bug was still present in Android 2.2.